# Can not update matrix entries for large matrices

Tags: r, matrix, memory

I am working with large matrices on a 32GB RAM Windows PC. For a certain size of matrix I am able to assign to individual cells of the matrix, this here:

```
> d_time <- matrix(NA, 20000, 100000)
>         d_time[1,1]
[1] NA
>         d_time[1,1] <- 1
>         d_time[1,1]
[1] 1
```

However, for larger matrices, this throws an error here:

```
> d_time <- matrix(NA, 30000, 100000)
>         d_time[1,1]
[1] NA
>         d_time[1,1] <- 1
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 22.4 Gb
> object.size(d_time)
12000000216 bytes
```

This second matrix is 11.2GB in size in RStudio.

Can anyone explain why this is happening, and is there anyway I can get this operation done?

Thanks.

Comment: I suspect your original matrix is of type logical because you've used `NA` so the entire thing is being copied when you try to assign a numeric value. Try instead to instantiate it with `NA_real_`.

Comment: You probably want to work with integers. `NA_integer_` and `d_time[1,1] <- 1L` , real/double takes double the space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NA` is of type `logical`. `1` is of type 'double`.

```
typeof(NA)
#> [1] "logical"
typeof(1)
#> [1] "double"
```

When you initialize the matrix with `NA`, it will be of type `logical`. If you try to change an element of that matrix to a `double`, it will upgrade the whole matrix, which requires creating a new one. A `double` object will require twice the memory as a `logical` object of the same size. You apparently don't have enough memory for a `double` matrix of that size.

If you really need a matrix that large, you have a couple options:

1. As suggested by @s_baldur, if the elements of the matrix are all `integer`, you can initialize the matrix with `d_time <- matrix(NA_integer_, 30000, 100000)` and update it with, e.g., `d_time[1,1] <- 1L`. This will require half the memory as a `double` matrix of the same size.
2. If a relatively large number of cells will remain empty (zero), work with [sparse matrices](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Matrix/index.html).

Comment: Thanks I have made changes along the lines suggested here and the code is fine. I think I found elsewhere that integer is the smallest type in R. There is no short, and booleans are the same size as integers?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.